# Linux - script to copy a line from one file to multiple other files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm stuck with this task:

I have a textfile 1.txt  where there is 1 variable in each line. I have a textfile 2.txt where I want to replace line 3 with the variable of 1.txt and save it under a directory which has the same name as the variable. My idea was this:

```
!/bin/bash

for i in `cat 1.txt`;
do awk '{ if (NR == 3) print $i; else print $0}' 2.txt > "/$i/2.txt";
done
```

The last part works, I get the file in the expected folder. But it is always the same file just copied, not modified.

Any help appreciated

Edit: to make it more clear, my 1.txt. contains data like:

```
variable1
variable2
variable3
```

each in one line.

I now want to edit a file 2.txt, insert variable1 in line 3 and save it to /variable1/2.txt
then again open file 2.txt, insert variable2 in line 3 and save it to /variable2/2.txt
and so on....

hope that makes it more clear ;)

Comment: If you could post a sample input and output that would help folks to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I understood your question.

```sh
while IFS= read -r lines; do
  [[ ! -d "/$lines" ]] && { mkdir -p "/$lines" || exit; }
  printf '%s\n' '3c' "$lines" . ,p Q | ed -s 2.txt > "/$lines/2.txt"
done < 1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite follow what you are doing but the following code is one way to do what you describe:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r variable; do
    mkdir "$variable"
    echo -e "\n\n$variable" > "${variable}/2.txt"
done < 1.txt
```

The output is:

```
$ cat variable?/2.txt 


variable1


variable2


variable3
```

**EDIT:** after reading the comment on the solution by @Jetchisel a similar solution using vims ex command is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r variable; do
    ex "+normal! 2G" "+normal o${variable}" "+wq" "${variable}/2.txt"
done < 1.txt
```